# LaTex Beamer: Frame title over two lines moves logo

Tags: beamer, logos, frame-title

I am just starting to do my presentations with LaTex beamer, so I am not so familiar with all the concepts. Right now I have the problem, that the logo changes its position, when the frametitle is so long, that it has to split into two lines. I insert the logo with:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
       \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.81\textwidth,7.2cm)
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.png}
        \end{textblock*}}
```

I want it to stay where it is indepenedet of the length of the framtitle. Can somebody explain me the problem? Thank you!
Here is a minimal example without titlepage etc.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, subcaption, tabularx, tikz, textpos}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\useinnertheme{circles}
\logo{\includegraphics[width = 3.5cm]{logo.png}}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
     \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} 




\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
   \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.81\textwidth,7.2cm)
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.png}
    \end{textblock*}}
\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{LIBS and Raman spectroscopy}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{LIBS and Raman spectroscopy for Solar System exploration}
\end{frame}

   \end{document}
```

[image: First slide where everthing is fine]
[image: Second slide where the logo is moved down]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack: Instead of abusing the `frametitle` to add your logo, abuse the `navigation symbols`

Also please don't load packages multiple times and you don't need `graphicx` with beamer.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{textpos}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption, tabularx, tikz, textpos}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\useinnertheme{circles}
\logo{\includegraphics[width = 3.5cm]{logo.png}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
     \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{LIBS and Raman spectroscopy}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{LIBS and Raman spectroscopy for Solar System exploration}
\end{frame}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you corrected? :)

Comment: @AndréC I corrected nothing, just replaced one hack with another :)

Comment: I misspoke, I'm sorry. The question code written by @Tini doesn't work, yours works, what did you do to make it work?

Comment: @AndréC Other than missing images, the code in the OP works for me. What errors do you get?

Comment: I can no longer see the image on the second slide of the slide show.

Comment: @AndréC A I understand it, this is exactly the problem of the OP that the logo gets pushed below the footline if the frametitle is too long.

Comment: Meanwhile, you explained what you did in your answer and I finally understood, thank you very much

Comment: @AndréC Oh, sorry! I assumed you had seen my edit, that what I meant with `replaced one hack with another`

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much, this is a nice solution :)